# AppStore trying to download app that's already downloaded

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, firefox

I restored my phone from a backup and the apps were synced with iTunes, but the App Store says it's trying to download apps that are already installed. It won't go passed the loading wheel and it's doing it with multiple apps.[image: firefox Is already installed]
[image: but it says it's not]

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again? Thus, have you tried to sign out and back in with your AppleID in the App Store?

Comment: Ive tried turning it off and on, holding the sleep/home, signing out restarting and signing back in, changing languages, continuously pressing the stop button in the App Store, and just letting it sit to see if it fixes itself.

Comment: What about syncing it via iTunes on your Mac/PC?

Comment: I'm about to try that.. if not I'm going to restore from a backup again.

Comment: Absolutely. That was my second call just in case this syncing wouldn't have worked. Let me know tho :)

Comment: I just trying syncing, it didn't work. So I'm going to try restoring again.

Comment: Totally, usually reinstalling updates works just fine. Let me know if restoring worked

Comment: Restoring from backup worked!

Comment: Yea. Then others who may have this problem have a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually such App Store issues are not easily fixable.

## First

Something you may try at first is the following:

1. **Restart** your iDevice
2. **Sign out** and **back in** with your AppleID I'm the App Store
3. **Sync** your iDevice using iTunes

---

## At last

If all the above possible solutions didn't work, you may want to restore your iDevice, so first of all you'll have to:

1. **Make** a **Backup** of your iDevice and save it either on iCloud or on to your Mac/PC.
2. **Erase all content** and data of your iDevice through **Settings** > **General** > **Reset** > **Erase All Content And Settings**.
3. Once you erased your content, and you initialize back your iDevice, when asking wether you want to setup your iDevice as new or **restore** a Backup, choose the second option, and select your **backup**.

   ---

For a reference and an official guide about successfully performing a restore, you may want to take a look at this [Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184).