# App Store sometimes can't install apps, iCloud icon appearing instead of INSTALL icon

Tags: iphone

App Store sometimes can't install apps, iCloud icon appearing instead of INSTALL icon, as in the attached screenshot. If i click iCloud icon it buffers some seconds & come backs to iCloud symbol.

[image: Screenshot of App Store showing iCloud icon instead of INSTALL icon]

Please tell me how to make the INSTALL icon appear again for these apps, instead of the iCloud icon? It usually appears for some apps that I've uninstalled before and I want to install again.

Comment: Hey, check this other question and tell me if helped you out solving your issue! http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245650/188552

Answer (score 1):

An iCloud icon means that you have bought this application before and this is the only different between showing this icon and `GET`/`INSTALL` icon.

You can not change the iCloud icon because it is bought and it can't be undone. If you are unable to get the application, maybe there are network issues. Try change the network you are connected to a more reliable network, and reboot your device.