# Downloading apps

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to update my apps on my phone but it isn't working at all. So I tried to uninstall my messenger 2 days ago and install it again but I can't install it  I don't know why. It always shows that "waiting" it isn't even loading. Now I don't have messenger  Pls help. Thanks

Comment: Hi Rey, welcome to the Apple Stack Exchange community! Have a look in here and tell me if those steps solved your issue! http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245650/188552

Comment: I'm afraid to restore my phone cause I forgot my apple id already :(

Comment: You will need it eventually, so best to recover it now. Start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Comment: Definitely agree, make sure you recover it first, check the [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com) page.

Answer (score 1):

iOS has one central download queue for all system tasks. Check iTunes Store->Downloads and Podcasts->Downloads to see if you have something tying up your downloads.